# What could this green box be in the engine bay of Renault Megane 1.5 dci diesel?

Tags: part-identification, renault, megane

As you can see in the picture below theres a big box looking thing in the engine bay of this diesel renault. What could this part be? I never seen anything like that before.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't see a battery in your engine compartment and the mystery object is right next to the fuse box, I think you'll find the battery under the cover. Probably to keep the battery terminals clean and to protect from short circuits if a mechanic drops a tool.

You should be able to pop the cover off without tools and take a peek.